# Where is the source code for the java compiler?

Tags: java, javac

I'm looking for the source code of Sun's standard java compiler, `javac`.

jdk1.6.0_07 has a few classes that are related, but they are interfaces
(`java.lang.Compiler` and `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`).  There's also some packages under `com.sun.mirror.*` and `com.sun.source.*`, which seem to be interfaces for representing the java abstract syntax tree.

But I can't find the compiler source - anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this site [The Java programming-language compiler (javac) group](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/). The sources are in the Mercurial repositories.

[jdk7/tl/langtools](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/langtools) (for JDK 1.7)

[jdk6/jdk6/langtools](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools) (for JDK 1.6)

In the header of the two sites I linked to you find download links for the sources (in bz2, zip and gz format)

There you have the sources in *src\share\classes\com\sun\tools\javac\*

Comment: thanks! Is the official sun one (that comes with the jdk), not a reimplementation?  BTW: The parser seems to be a simple recursive descent parser, closely modeling the JLS http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/langtools/file/a9008b46db24/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/parser/Parser.jav.
 so you can trace through the grammar.

Comment: It should be the official one. As since approx. 2006 the JDK/JRE are opensource. There was a time when certain pieces of JDK/JRE maybe tools too weren't completely opensource as there where some licensing issues. If you want to know since what build exactly the javac is opensource I suggest writing to the appropriate openjdk mailinglist

Comment: Thanks, looking through the source, some have the Sun copyright notice, and some explicitly say their API isn't Sun-supported.

Comment: I just wanted to say how much I appreciate your answer.  It was an Indiana moment to trace through the parsing of familiar parts of a java program (e.g. a class declaration); like secret knowledge.  Even more affirming was to recognize the recursive descent parsing as exactly the same flavour as parsing code I've written recently:  in this, the java engineers are my peers.

Answer (score 2):

[It's here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/)